# TableView with NSFetchedResultsController is Flickering so much

Tags: swift, uitableview, merge, nsfetchedresultscontroller, flicker

I got a tableView with FRC. I use NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy as mergePolicy for managedContext save.

The problem is when a record updated "didChange" delegate method is calling 3 times. It's calling for in that order insert, delete, update. So my tableView flickering so much.

How can i prevent that? Because every record of my application is being  updated 4 times so tableView is flickering 12 times..

My delegate methods:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex) as IndexSet, with: .none)
    case .move:
        break
    case .update:
        break
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    print("cs \(type.rawValue)")

    switch type {

    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath! as IndexPath], with: .none)
        break
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
        break
    case .move:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .none)

        //tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
        break
    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
        break
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using. Are you using controllerWillChangeContent  and controllerDidChangeContent for batch operations ?

Comment: Yes, i'm using. I edit the question.

Comment: did you try using beginUpdates and endUpdates? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates , not sure if it will help, but could

Comment: @Luzo thanks for advice. I shared code in the question. What am i missing?

Comment: @Daedelus try to comment this line `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)`, just to see if it is the line causing it, might be that begin and end updates are just enough for your update

Comment: @Luzo beginUpdates and endUpdates are not enough to update.  I got constraints in my entity. When a record is about to save and constraints are matched. First, new record is inserting tableView then old record is deleting then update is calling as NSFetchedResultsChangeType.

Comment: this http://www.fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2013/02/19/uitableview-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller-updates-done-right/ might help you, guy is queuing updates, not sure how much is it applicable here. Anyways you will have to build mechanism for doing all changes regarding cell at once otherwise it will be flickering that much.

Comment: Thanks for attention @Luzo i'm making a realtime chat application. Maybe  NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy  is not suitable for that application. I will try to use NSErrorMergePolicy with save or update mekanism to reduce flickering. I will announce result here.

Comment: As i said NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy is not suitable for that application. I developed that approach; 1- fetchRecord 2- if record found update it 3- if record not found save it. So only insert and update actions happening.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not cleaning your database. Flickering is possible because of this:

```
        service.fetchDatasWith { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):

            DataManager.clearData() // Cleaning
            DataManager.saveInCoreDataWith(array: data) // Saving again

            print(data)
        case .error(let message):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                AlertPresenter.presentAlertWith(title: "Error", message: message, controller: self)
            }
        }
    }
```